# MySQL Query to return Wordpress Post Keys in separate columns

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Given this MySQL query on a Wordpress database:

```
SELECT posts.ID as POST_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ', ') as POST_LATLONG
FROM wp_2_posts as posts
LEFT JOIN wp_2_postmeta postmeta ON posts.id = postmeta.post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'merchant_long'
OR meta_key = 'merchant_lat'
GROUP BY posts.ID
```

Which returns this:

```
POST_ID | POST_LATLONG
231       28.594733, -81.350772
232       28.541043, -81.379004
233       38.910831, -77.157638
```

How can I separate the POST_LATLONG column into two distinct columns named POST_LAT and POST_LONG so the result looks like:

```
POST_ID    |    POST_LAT    |    POST_LONG
231             28.594733        -81.350772
232             28.541043        -81.379004
233             38.910831        -77.157638
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT posts.ID as POST_ID,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ', '), ', ', 2) AS POST_LAT,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ', '), ', ', -2) AS POST_LONG
FROM wp_2_posts as posts
LEFT JOIN wp_2_postmeta postmeta ON posts.id = postmeta.post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'merchant_long'
OR meta_key = 'merchant_lat'
GROUP BY posts.ID
```